# Create Table in transaction in SQLite in-memory database not being rolled back

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, transactions

Does SQLite in-memory support transactions around table creations? I would expect the code below to begin the transaction, create the table, rollback the transaction, then have nothing left. Instead, the table appears to still be around.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
conn = engine.connect()

try:
    with conn.begin():
        conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE test (
            "index" BIGINT,
            a BIGINT,
            b BIGINT
        )''')
        assert False  # rollback
except AssertionError:
    pass

tables = inspect(engine).get_table_names()
assert tables == [], tables
```

The assertion fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3418, in run_code
        exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-2-9e170787a857>", line 21, in <module>
        assert tables == [], tables
AssertionError: ['test']
```

Here's the engine output:

```
2021-03-01 12:16:16,872 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2021-03-01 12:16:16,872 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2021-03-01 12:16:16,872 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2021-03-01 12:16:16,873 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2021-03-01 12:16:16,873 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2021-03-01 12:16:16,873 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine CREATE TABLE test (
    "index" BIGINT,
    a BIGINT,
    b BIGINT
)
2021-03-01 12:16:16,873 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2021-03-01 12:16:16,874 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
2021-03-01 12:16:16,874 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name
2021-03-01 12:16:16,874 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
```

Edit: SQLAlchemy version is `1.3.23`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pysqlite DBAPI has several known issues with transaction processing, including transactional DDL. They are discussed in the SQLAlchemy documentation for the SQLite dialect:

[Transactional DDL](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#transactional-ddl)

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to particularly [link to their workaround](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html#pysqlite-serializable) that I verified fixes this example. Note that the syntax changes slightly between 1.13 and 1.14.